# CoefficientList for unbounded list of variables

Tags: coefficients

Consider a polynomial: `expr = Sum[x[k] a[k] + x[k], {k, 0, K}];`

I want to determine the coefficients for variables `x[k]` for each k, so the desirable output is `(a[k]+1)`(not numerical).

EDIT (using the comment of @yurie):
the working code is:
`CoefficientList[expr[[1]], x[k]]`

Comment: For this simple example you can use `Part` to extract the term in sum, and then apply `CoefficientList`, `CoefficientList[expr[[1]],x[k]]`

Comment: Hi. If you have multiple sums in the expression (or even just one), this could work `Coefficient[#, x[k]] & /@ Cases[expr, Sum[a_, _] -> a, {0, Infinity}]`